# Handling WCF exceptions/faults along with FaultException AND IErrorHandler

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, exception

I'm interested in implementing a proper exception handling for my WCF application. After a quick google ride, I've come across two solutions.

1. Providing `FaultExceptions` for the client.
2. General exception handling using `IErrorHandler`.

What I didn't found, though, was a practical example that combines the two methods - *if this is even considered as good practice*.

My thoughts:

**Throwing FaultExceptions with own detail types**

```
throw new FaultException<StackOverflowFault>(
    new StackOverflowFault(StackOverflowFaultCode.Rules,
        "This question is not considered as constructive."));
```

**Catching unhandled exceptions with `IErrorHandler` and log them.**

```
public bool HandleError(Exception ex) {
    try {
        SomeLogger.Error(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception) {
        // Well, there was an exception handling the
        // exception :(
        // -> Drop the exception and throw a new one
        throw new Exception("Unknown exception occured.");
    }
}
```

**...and provide faults based on the exception type**

*(not everything is for the clients eyes!)*

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault){
    if(error is FaultException) {
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, ((FaultException<StackOverflowFault>)error).Reason)
    } else if(error is SqlException) {
        // What would Jon Skeet do?
    }   
}
```

---

**My question**

Is this considered as okay practice? And: If I'm already throwing FaultException in the application that are suitable for the client - does it makes sense to let them be handled by `IErrorHandler` (*which does it automatically*)?

Comment: +1 for referencing Mr. Skeet in your question!

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to implement IErrorHandler. This is because:

1. **Your code isn’t the only potential source of exceptions.** The methods you call (or a bug) might result in a .NET Exception. If you don’t handle that exception somewhere and aren’t using [IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.includeexceptiondetailinfaults.aspx) (which you shouldn't in production) this will look like a service crash.
2. **Separation of Concerns**: Any business layer called by the service code should not reference WCF (`System.ServiceModel`) and therefore should be throwing standard .NET exceptions. Keeping the business layer unaware of how its hosted makes it more portable and more testable.
3. [`FaultContract`] types need to be specified on the [`OperationContract`]. In larger applications you want the Fault generation to be centralized… In other words know that a particular IErrorHandler returns a particular set of Faults so that you can validate the Contracts Faults types are right. Throwing a Fault type that the contract’s method does not explicitly support is a nasty runtime error.

You could copy and paste a try/catch block in all your service methods to throw a FaultException, but it’s a horrible code smell and is the exact functionality that IErrorHandler is giving you as a behavior. So use IErrorHandler instead.

Combining the two models is possible. For example have IErrorHandler process FaultExceptions as needed, but this is not a common practice.

Comment: I fully understand the power and necessity of IErrorHandler in a WCF service. And wrapping every single method into a try-catch is not was I was heading to. But I need a way to tell the client when he's doing something wrong, preferably by using enumerations as fault-code. The client requests 3 apples, but there are only 2 left, then a OperationFault would be raised along with "NotEnoughApples" in detail. But when I implement IErrorHandler, this fault is being caughted as plain Exception, - what seems silly to me. Or do I understand something wrong here?

Comment: "The client requests 3 apples, but there are only 2 left" - This doesn't sound like an exceptional circumstance.  Perhaps the result of the method should return a meaningful result, but not an exception/fault